# Create web shortcut in windows in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, shortcut

[Create shortcut files in Windows 10 using Python 3.7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53268792/create-shortcut-files-in-windows-10-using-python-3-7-1)

this is for shortcut to local files

How to create a shortcut to https://xxxxx.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be needing [winshell](https://winshell.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for this, which would make finding user-specific paths and folders easy. Here's the script:

```
import os, winshell
desktop = winshell.desktop()
path = os.path.join(desktop, "ShortcutName.url")
target = "https://xxxxx.com"
shortcut = file(path, 'w')
shortcut.write('[InternetShortcut]\n')
shortcut.write('URL=%s' % target)
shortcut.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('shortcut.url', mode='w', newline='\r\n') as f:
    f.write("[InternetShortcut]\nURL=http://example.com")
```

Option `newline='\r\n'` is required to make sure your script will create valid Windows shortcut while running on Mac or Linux.